# how do i change openssl configuration?

Tags: php, apache, openssl, digital-certificate

Ok now its plain and simple i have generated a openssl certificate with php but when i view it, then it shows me the same issued by and issued to how do i change the issued by things now i know that we need to add a ca while signing the certificate from openssl_csr_sign() like

openssl_csr_sign ( mixed $csr , mixed $cacert , mixed $priv_key , int $days [, array $configargs [, int $serial = 0 ]] )

where $cacert is the ca certificate and provide a ca certificate in it but when i do that it doesn't do any changes my main guess is that i have to edit the openssl.cnf but i don't get it where to edit to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, if it's a self signed/ self issued certificate, that's how it's going to be. You need to get a third party certificate from a trusted source (verisign etc.) if you want to have a valid "trusted" certificate issued by someone other than yourself.

Comment: What i want is that i have a project which is under my other company now my head company will issue that certificate to the project that's it how do i do that in openssl.